# Laravel custom Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

Hi I want to use routes like this for a page

```
Route::get('{slug?}-{newsSlug?}-{id?}', array('as' => 'subpages', 'uses' => 'HomeController@subpages' ));
```

It does not work like this

```
Route::get('{slug?}/{newsSlug?}/{id?}', array('as' => 'subpages', 'uses' => 'HomeController@subpages' ));
```

This way the other pages do not work naturally.
Could you suggest me a solution about this.

Comment: You want do define a `sub domain` route? like admin.site.com?

Comment: No. I just do not want to put a constant text on the top of the route. news/{newsSlug?}/{id?} -> It is not like this

Comment: www.test.com/this-news-slug-category-id

Comment: well if you have other routes with similar path then I believe `constant/{slug?}/{newsSlug?}/{id?}` i.e having a fixed constant is the only way to not have conflicts with other routes

Comment: I think it should be a way

Comment: What is your problem? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Where you define a route like this

```
Route::get('{slug?}-{newsSlug?}-{id?}'...)
```

without a constant, it means it will cover most cases of routing, which is why other pages do not work.

For them to work, you need to put that code at the end of your routes file, so that other routes will have precedence.